# How to remove quotation and spaces arround numbers in a CSV file using sed?

Tags: regex, sed

I have some numbers in a CSV file which I'm trying to remove quotations and spaces arround it.

Input:
`1," 23","45","67 ",89`

Expected output: `1,23,45,67,89`

I'm trying to remove with:

```
sed -r -e 's#\"[ ]*\([0-9]+\)[ ]*\"#\1#g' file.csv
```

But I'm getting the error "sed: -e expression #1, char 38: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS", if I remove the`-r` option, I don't get the error, but it does not work either.

Comment: If you are using the `-r` switch, you shouldn't be escaping your capture groups. Try removing the backslashes before the `(` and the `)`.

Comment: thanks! my regex seens to be working now :)

Comment: No problem. If your input may contain other, non-numerical fields, then are you happy with how your current regex deals with them? If not, could you show an example of how they should be dealt with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tom Fenech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2088135/tom-fenech) provided the crucial pointer in a comment:

The **only problem with the OP's command is a minor syntax problem**:

Since `sed` is used with **`-r`** in order to activate ***extended* regular expressions**, **`(` and `)` - for defining capture groups - must NOT be `\`-escaped**.
(By contrast, when `sed` is used *without* `-r`, *basic* regular expressions must be used, where such escaping is needed.)

The correct form is therefore (`\` before `(` and `)` removed):

```
sed -r 's#\"[ ]*([0-9]+)[ ]*\"#\1#g' file.csv
```

<sup>If you want the command to work on OSX also, use `-E` instead of `-r`.</sup>

Alternatively, for maximum portability (POSIX compliance) you could just use `\{1,\}` instead of `+` and do away with the `-r` switch entirely:

```
sed 's#\"[ ]*\([0-9]\{1,\}\)[ ]*\"#\1#g' file.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below perl command,

```
$ echo '1," 23","45","67 ",89, "foo" , "bar" ' | perl -pe 's/[" ]+(\d+)[ "]+/\1/g'
1,23,45,67,89, "foo" , "bar"
```

Comment: looks like this will remove any quotes and spaces on the file, which is not my intention because the file have much more stuff

Comment: This is a more permissive reformulation (e.g., it would also match something like `""5" "`) of the OP's solution using a different language (Perl). However, the only problem with the OP's `sed` command is a minor syntax error.

Comment: @mklement0 i think the contents are comma seperated. And this is the one blink on my mind after reading the input and the expected output.

Comment: Yes, input is comma-separated (the OP mentions CSV and the sample input has commas) - I don't understand the rest of your comment, however, and how it relates to mine.